# Drools: Get stateless session results using Query

Tags: java, drools, stateless

As it comes from the official `Drools` [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch07.html) it is possible to obtain results from stateless session using `Query`.

```
// Set up a list of commands
List cmds = new ArrayList();
cmds.add( CommandFactory.newSetGlobal( "list1", new ArrayList(), true ) );
cmds.add( CommandFactory.newInsert( new Person( "jon", 102 ), "person" ) );
cmds.add( CommandFactory.newQuery( "Get People" "getPeople" );

// Execute the list
ExecutionResults results =
  ksession.execute( CommandFactory.newBatchExecution( cmds ) );

// Retrieve the ArrayList
results.getValue( "list1" );
// Retrieve the inserted Person fact
results.getValue( "person" );
// Retrieve the query as a QueryResults instance.
results.getValue( "Get People" );
```

In the sample below, `Get People` is a drools `Query` which basically returns an object or a list of objects form a stateless (!) session.

In my project I need to obtain an object created in stateless `Kie session`, so I've created a `Query`:

```
query "getCustomerProfileResponse"
    $result: CustomerProfileResponse()
end
```

The `CustomerProfileResponse` object is constructing and creating in `RHS`:

```
insert(customerProfileResponse);
```

I wrote the following code to execute commands in batch mode and query the resulted `CustomerProfileResponse`:

```
// Creating a batch list
List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<Command<?>>(10);
commands.add(CommandFactory.newInsert(customerProfile));
commands.add(CommandFactory.newQuery(GET_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_RESPONSE, 
GET_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_RESPONSE));

// GO!
ExecutionResults results = kSession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands));

FlatQueryResults queryResults = (FlatQueryResults) results.getValue(GET_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_RESPONSE); // size() is 0!
```

But `queryResults` returns an empty list.

I was searching Stack Overflow for the similar questions and find out that it is not possible to run queries against stateless sessions in Drools using batch mode since the session closes immediately after `execute()` method is called, and the solution is to inject an empty `CustomerProfileResponse` object along with `CustomerProfile` in request.

Does anybody can shed some light onto the issue?

Comment: After some researchings I've also figured out that this query runs correctly in case of the 'dummy' or 'plain' query object is inserted into session as a batch command before the actual rule execution. Don't actually sure whether it is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding CommandFactory.newFireAllRules() after newInsert and before NewQuery should solve the problem. See http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-Query-in-stateless-knowledge-session-returns-no-results-td3210735.html

> Your rules will not fire until the all the command shave been executed. i.e. the implicit fireAllRules() is once all commands have been executed. Which means the query will be invoked before your rule fires to insert the object.
>
> Instead you need to add the FireAllRules command before executing the query.